# How to check whether a Tibco EMS exclusive queue has an active consumer?

Tags: c++, tibco, ems

I am developing an application which consumes from a Tibco EMS Queue which has exclusive property set. I shall be able to run multiple instances of my application in Active and Standby mode. 
When the application is in standby mode it should not create a consumer to the exclusive queue.

I have implemented the below solution but am looking for a better way to do this?

Currently am using tibemsQueueInfo_GetReceiverCount() to get the receiver count. But this API gives all the consumers created for the queue and I have to call 2 more APIs before this.

Is there a single API that would just return that the queue has an active consumer?

```
status = tibemsAdmin_Create(&admin, server, userName, password, sslParams);
    if (status != TIBEMS_OK)
    {
        baseUtils_print("tibemsAdmin_Create create failed: %s\n", tibemsStatus_GetText(status));
        exit(1);
    }
    baseUtils_print("Amin creation successful\n");

    status = tibemsAdmin_GetQueue(admin, &queueInfo, name);
    if (status != TIBEMS_OK)
    {
        baseUtils_print("tibemsAdmin_GetQueue create failed: %s\n", tibemsStatus_GetText(status));
        exit(1);
    }
    baseUtils_print("Admin GetQueue successful \n");

    status = tibemsQueueInfo_GetReceiverCount(queueInfo, &receiverCount);
    if (status != TIBEMS_OK)
    {
        baseUtils_print("tibemsQueueInfo_GetReceiverCount create failed: %s\n", tibemsStatus_GetText(status));
        exit(1);
    }
    baseUtils_print("Queue: '%s', Active Consumers = '%d'\n",name, receiverCount);
    bool flag = true;
    int prevCount = 0;
    while(receiverCount)
    {
        prevCount = receiverCount;

        if(flag)
        {
            cout << "Consumer in Standby mode..."<<endl;
            flag = false;;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));       
        status = tibemsAdmin_GetQueue(admin, &queueInfo, name);

        if (status != TIBEMS_OK)
        {
            baseUtils_print("tibemsAdmin_GetQueue create failed: %s\n", tibemsStatus_GetText(status));
            exit(1);
        }

        status = tibemsQueueInfo_GetReceiverCount(queueInfo, &receiverCount);
        if (status != TIBEMS_OK)
        {
            baseUtils_print("tibemsQueueInfo_GetReceiverCount create failed: %s\n", tibemsStatus_GetText(status));
            exit(1);
        }

        if(receiverCount != prevCount)
            cout << "current receiver count = "<<receiverCount<<endl;
    }
    cout << "Consumer mode is Active"<<endl;

    status = tibemsSession_CreateConsumer(session,
            &msgConsumer,destination,NULL,TIBEMS_FALSE);
    if (status != TIBEMS_OK)
    {
        fail("Error creating tibemsMsgConsumer", errorContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there isn't an easier API. If there would be a 'direct-access' method it would be on tibemsAdmin, but there isn't.
And structurally the API kind of makes sense: you have an Admin Object, then get to the Queue Object and then ask for properties of that Queue Object.

Also the code below will **not work**, so the fact if a consumer is 'the second in line' is only established after the consumer is created and silently waits for its turn.

```
while(true) // or better: while( !isStopped() ) ...
{
    status = tibemsSession_CreateConsumer(session, &msgConsumer,destination,NULL,TIBEMS_FALSE);
    if (status != TIBEMS_OK)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3)); 
        cout << "Consumer in Standby mode ??"<<endl;      
    }
    else
    {
       cout << "Consumer mode is Active ??"<<endl;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: tibemsSession_CreateConsumer() always returns TIBEMS_OK even though there is an existing active consumer for the exclusive queue. If this API return some other status code then it is easy but it doesn't.

Comment: Hi Deepak, yes, unfortunately you are totally right - I'll edit this code. the exclusive access state is only established once the consumer is created.